# Store NFA into data structure

Tags: parsing, data-structures, lex, dfa, nfa

I am provided with a NFA and I need to use a data structure (I can not use recursive descent parser) for storing it. Once the NFA is stored in a data structure I am given a string to check if the string is valid according to the NFA given or not.

Can someone please suggest a data structure for storing a NFA? Also if there are any opensource c language examples that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

An NFA is just a set of triples `State x Input -> State`. It's usually convenient to represent a State with a small integer in a consecutive range starting at 0 (or some other defined starting point). Input symbols can also be mapped onto small integers, either directly (ascii code if all the transitions are ascii characters) or by keeping an inventory while you read the machine. Making a list of triples is highly inefficient and making a hash table is overkill; a plausible intermediate is a two-dimensional array. Remember that the machine is *Nondeterministic*, so a given [state, input symbol] pair might map to a *set* of next states.

You can determinize the NFA into a DFA using the Subset Construction. That simplifies the data structure but it can also blow up exponentially in size.